# MVC.NET role based authorization on legacy .asmx service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asmx, asp.net-identity

I have an mvc5 website with **asp.net identity**, and on it some .asmx legacy services.

On my old website with  asp.net membership model, I used

```
 <location path="~/myservice.asmx">
   <system.web>
       <authorization>
         <deny users="*"/>
         <allow roles="AuthorizedRole"/>
       </authorization>
     </system.web>   
 </location>
```

and it worked, but on the new site it doesn't work, as well as the mvc attributes

```
[Authorize(Roles = "AuthorizedRole")]
```

how can I make authorization in this case?

Comment: Do you have the membership enabled in your mvc5 web.config file?

Comment: No, because I want to use asp.net identity model. I want to use asp.net identity roles. Can membership use identity roles?